images not displaying on firebase hosting
i have react + vite app that's hosting on firebase.
the problem is that images are not loading, leaving only default blank img, here's the screenshot:
screenshot
i'm pretty sure the firebase just can't find images, or it's just me who chooses the wrong paths to images. here's example of how i use imgs:
            <img src="src/assets/logo.png" alt="main logo" />
            <img src="/src/assets/icons/AboutUsIcon.png" alt="about us" />
            <img src="/src/assets/icons/blogIcon.png" alt="blog" />



as you can see from the paths, my images located in src/assets folder.
after research my guess is that the problem in my firebase.json, that's looking like this:
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  }
}



The images are in your app's src directory, not any public directory or Firebase. The project's src directory isn't accessible when the app is built, and deployed/served from a hosting service.
Import and reference them in code accordingly.
Example:
import logo from "/assets/logo.png";
import aboutUsIcon from "/assets/icons/AboutUsIcon.png";
import blogIcon from "/assets/icons/blogIcon.png";

...

<img src={logo} alt="main logo" />
<img src={aboutUsIcon} alt="about us" />
<img src={blogIcon} alt="blog" />


thanks, it helped. i personally don't like this way, since i have to import so much things, but i guess there's no other option

@QFaZoPlay You could create an index.js file in these directories where you import the images there and then re-export them as named exports, then you could import them, something like import { logo, aboutUsIcon, blogIcon } from '/assets/images';. It's not a vast improvement, but it helps consuming code be a bit more clean.
